# Work computer hard wired to home modem

Tags: privacy, wifi

I took my office desktop computer home and plugged it into the router. I work for a private company and one of the owners went to school for computer programing/information security/etc). Can they see the browsing I do on my iPhone? Or on my Windows laptop (WiFi connected)?
Is this possible?
The desktop computer has no WiFi capability. Just a blue internet cable.
If they can - what can I do to limit what they see?

Comment: Question is not looks like a security problem? better to ask this question on https://superuser.com

Comment: Normally they will not see traffic from the other devices, unless they actually try to hack your network. To prevent any kind of access to your network you need network separation. Some routers have this built in as "guest network".

Comment: Thanks Steffen!!! 
Thats what my research shows too - i need to be a guest on my wifi or my work computer needs to be the guest. The router i have is a modem/wifi-router combo - pretty new tech i think. I am pretty sure the hardwired work computer cannot be “guested”...?

Comment: @user253388: Depends on the router. AVM Fritz!Box for example (very common in Germany) allows to dedicate one of the LAN ports for guest network.